# Laravel Livewire does not register actions

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have rappasoft datatable package which uses laravel livewire for server rendering.

In that package I have dropdown method named compare which compares selected (with bulk) products and returns view which is loaded as a modal...

Here is code for this return:

```
 $param = view('return.view.for.comparing', compact(somedata...))->render();
```

When everything loads it is working fine, but I want to add one more component in this view which will pull some data from external API and update values in this "modal".

```
<td>
   @if($p->param)
      <livewire:get-external-data :product="$product"></livewire:get-external-data>
   @endif
</td>
```

I get `$product` from the loop where this component is.

Now this component only has button which should trigger method but that never gets executed. I don't have any errors in console nor it dumps me data. Also, on network tab I see there are not registered any requests.

Component has only 1 div (parent one) everything is inside of it and since I don't have @livewireStyles or @livewireScripts I tried to load them too but still the same, also this is included into layout which does have styles and scripts so I am not really sure why this does not work.

Here is code of the button and method from the component that should run:

```
<button wire:click="getExternalData" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">{{ __('Get external data') }}</button>


public function getExternalData()
{
   dd('clicked');
}
```

Comment: You have to keep track of the components in a loop using `:wire:key="$product->id"`. Docs: https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/nesting-components#keyed-components

Comment: @Max I have `wire:key="{{$product->id}}_product"` on my button but still does not recognise any actions. Even if I did not have wire:key it should at least send error request or false data, but I literally don't get anything nor on console nor on network tab :3

Comment: The attribute should have an `:` on the start. Like this: `:wire:key="{{$product->id}}_product"`. 
What livewire version are you using? For version 3 this will be slightly different: `:key="$todo->id" ` Docs: https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/nesting#rendering-children-in-a-loop

Comment: @Max I am using livewire v2, also I have tried with and without `:`.  Still does not work

Comment: A `:` before `wire` indicates that you want the information between the quotes to be processed as PHP code. You are using standard blade templating, so you do not need the leading `:`.

Comment: E.g., `wire:key="{{$product->id}}_product"` is equivalent to `:wire:key="$product->id.'_product'"`. Not what is written above.

Comment: I have done it other way since this might be lw bug. Thanks for trying to help